# How to export grid data to excel?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am doing one project using kendo controls. In this grid export functionality is main issue. I am trying this it’s working fine, but when click on button only first page data is exported and footer also exported to excel. But i want to export all (rows) records in grid to excel

And my Code:

```
$(“#btnExport”).click(function(e) {
   window.open(‘data:application/vnd.ms-excel,’ + $(‘#grid’).html());
   e.preventDefault();     
});
```

Comment: if you use paging in grid then you have to remove paging..and then export grid...

Comment: sorry bro paging is  must and should for my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Correct but alternate answer :-

Make a New Temp Page and on btnExport click use javascript window.open('your temp page url') function

On temp page put GridView and Export Code..

On Page Load..fire Export code...

and remove paging on temp page...

Comment: Ok i will try that but here only current page is exporting